# Use domain class from main app in plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have to migrate a project from grails 1.3.5 to 2.2.4. In custom plugin there is a dependency to a class in main app.

```
class Comment {
    ...
    Person person
    ...
}
```

**Comment** is a domain class in plugin, **Person** is a domain class in main app. The app runs well on 1.3.5, but fails on 2.2.4. IDEA hilights **Person** as not found class on both versions of grails. Any ideas why it's runs well on 1.3.5 but fails on 2.2.4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Grails 1.3.5 but in 2.x is not possible to reference application classes in a plugin.

If you think about it, something is not right with your model, because a plugin should be an independent functionality, that can be plugged in any application.

Comment: I know, but it's damn support (=. Maybe there is a workaround for this?

Comment: Transform your domain classes in a plugin, that will be referenced in the application. Make the Comment plugin dependent on this new one.

Comment: Don't wont cos the person is a part of Acegi plugin. It's a bad idea to move generated classes to somewhere.

Comment: Well, you still have a design problem. Something must go to the application or to the plugin.